# abrir ventana modal específica según que se clickea

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal, gallery

Creé una galería de imágenes desde javascript a partir de tres arrays diferentes; y mediante una función. Quisiera que cuando yo clickeo una foto al azar se despliegue un modal con la foto clicada en tamaño aumentado. Dejo el código a continuación.

```
      $('#gallery').append(`<h2 class= "title">Galería de imágenes</h2>`)

          function addPictures(array) {
            console.log(array)
            for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                $('#gallery').append(`<div class="picture">
                            <img src="${array[i]}">
                      </div>
    `)
                            
  }

};
addPictures(roomsPictures);
addPictures(restaurant);
addPictures(spaAndPool);
```

Comment: Interesante... Sin embargo, no está claro lo que preguntas. Si tu pregunta es "Cómo lo hago?", hay miles de posibles respuestas. Qué modal estás utilizando? Bootstrap? Estás usando jQueryUI? Tu pregunta es DEMASIADO amplia. Por favor edítala y preséntanos con el **problema específico** con el que te estás encontrando

Comment: No estoy muy seguro de como editarla para que se entienda bien.. modal no estoy utilizando ninguno, no se como hacerlo y es lo que pregunto. Estoy usando jquery común; la versión 3.6.0 y aunque si estoy usando bootstrap, no utilizo ningún componente para esta galería. La pregunta si es "¿cómo lo hago?", y ese es el código que tengo. A partir de esas líneas se crea una galería con 15 fotos en tamaño acorde al dispositivo. Quisiera dar un click en cualquiera de esas fotos y que se despliegue una ventana con dicha foto pero en tamaño grande. @Arriel

Comment: Bueno... empecemos investigando, entonces. Comienza por implementar un modal sencillo. Un modal que se abra al dar click a un botón/link. Puedes darle una mirada al [boostrap modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/). Intenta hacer que funcione en tu página, y ya llevas el primer paso.